# Do we want weekly topic challenges here on Biology?

Tags: discussion

A great suggestion from Jon Ericson is to have [Weekly Topic Challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work), these would involve 4 steps:

**Step 1:** Ask for topic ideas.

**Step 2:** Post a challenge.

**Step 3:** Profit!!!! Tally the results.

**Step 4:** Repeat until no more topics are left.

For the full details, follow the link above.

What do people think of this idea?  Do we want this on Biology.se?

Here's one I started on [**Gardening & Landscaping** beta](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge) We have 1 [completed challenge](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/602/weekly-topic-challenge-terminology-completed) and are working on the [next](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/605/weekly-topic-challenge-seed-saving).

Please post your feedback to this idea as an answer.